# Node.Js - multiple workers on 1 cpu? (Cluster)

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing

The situation is as following:

I have a node.js server with a script which takes pretty long before it finishes.
The script is getting an ID, looks up in a database which pictures belongs to this ID, and then it cache's the images and once all images are cached, it finishes.

Now the problem is that its possible there are 2 or more people at the same time using this feature. And once there are multiple people trying to get all these images, the images are combined to eachother and person A gets the pictures of person A + B. and also person B gets the pictures of A+B.

Now i know that a worker require's 1 cpu. i edited this so i can have multiple workers on 1 CPU. But they only switch from workers when the CPU usage is really high.
I want to switch workers when someone is already busy with getting these images, and someone else is trying to also get his/her images. (which are different for every person.)

How can this be done? Because the cluster only switches workers when the CPU usage is high. Or did i understand this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

The clustering is not made for that.

You use clusters to avoid situations where one core is 100% busy while other cores are barely doing anything - like this:

[image]

You have a problem with improperly handling concurrent requests in your code and clustering will not solve that. Even if you have a cluster of 1000 workers there can still be situation when you get 1001 requests and all bets are off.

Working with Node you always have to take into account concurrency because if you don't you will not be able to use a simple solution like add clustering to solve the problems.

You didn't show even a single line of code so it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with it, but there is clearly a problem with improper request handling. Maybe you use global variables? Maybe you store some state in the wrong scope? The situation that you describe should never happen in any Node application, and the solution you're asking about would not solve it anyway. You need to fix your code.